# Mongodb find array of ids

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have one array which has  document ids.:

```
var ids = [ '5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc26', '5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc28' ]
```

I have one collection called Machines with documents inside.
[image]

I am trying to get documents from Machines collection using ids which are in my array.

```
Machines.find({ _id : { $in : ids } }).fetch();
```

this returns []

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var ids = [ ObjectId("5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc26"), ObjectId("5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc28") ]
```

Because Mongodb stores id as `ObjectId("Actual Id")`

Answer (score 1):

Your

> ```
> var ids = [ '5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc26', '5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc28' ]
> ```

looks like they're either hex string or native MongoDB BSON type ObjectID.

Try this for Meteor's Mongo:

```js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const ids = [
  new Mongo.ObjectID('5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc26'),
  new Mongo.ObjectID('5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc28'),
]

Machines.find({ _id : { $in : ids } }).fetch();
```

For better syntax, use `.map()` to get a new array of `Mongo.ObjectID` type IDs.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const ids = ['5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc26', '5b3c7db4c079dc17dc75fc28', ...];
const mongoIds = ids.map(id => new Mongo.ObjectID(id));

Machines.find({ _id : { $in : mongoIds } }).fetch();

// if ids were ObjectIDs instead of literal strings
const objectIdToMongoIds = ids.map(id => new Mongo.ObjectID(id.toString()));
Machines.find({ _id: { $in: objectIdToMongoIds } });
```

[meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) [mongo](/questions/tagged/mongo) [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `Machine.findById(req.params.id, () => {}`